# S3 allow only encrypted policy doesn't work

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using the example [provided by Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) to disallow uploads to S3 that don't have encryption turned on, like so:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PutObjPolicy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

When I then try to upload using a pre-signed URL, I get an "access denied" back from S3. If I remove the policy (it is the only one set on the bucket), it works. The pre-signed URL looks like

```
'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.txt?Signature=6UxyYNjZDLFHlibwx3Aypicx7o4%3D&Expires=1432059554&AWSAccessKeyId=AKI1234567890&x-amz-server-side-encryption=AES256'
```

What is going wrong?

EDIT: I generate the URL using the [generate_url](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.generate_url) function that AWS boto provides.

Comment: How are you creating the pre signed url?

Comment: @rohit I'm using Amazon's boto library

Comment: Can you share the code? Are you setting the correct verb(put) when generating the pre signed url?

Comment: On my phone but simply using the function that Bucket provides. I tried some variations of the url and verb and they result in different errors. Only by removing the policy it works.

Comment: One last question. When you upload the file without the policy on the bucket then if you check the console what does the encryption type look like on the object?

Comment: It reports it as server side encrypted, AES256. If you remove the query parameter from the PUT it invalidates the signature, so as long as uploads are only possible via the pre-signed URLs I generate, I think I'm ok.

Comment: Try changing `StringNotEquals` to `StringEquals` and see whether it works. That would help determine whether the condition is the part that is denying access. Also, try uploading NOT encrypted and see if it works.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein good idea! Changing to StringEquals gives it access. It looks like that condition is not available on pre-signed URLs, it only looks at headers. I tested with headers and it works as expected even though the pre-signed content determines what actually happens. If you put that in an answer I'll accept that.

Comment: @w00t How are you doing the upload? Are you doing a Version 2 or a Version 4 signature (eg https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html), or some other method? I can't see a way to specify SSE on a form upload. (Or is that what your previous comment meant?)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I simply do a PUT on the generated URL (example in question) without any other headers. Works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you cannot specify SSE as part of the PUT, or the condition is not available on a pre-signed URL since it only look at the headers.

I tested by uploading from a form (using a POST) and the policy kicks-in to block the upload because it is not server-side encrypted, yet there is not way to specify encryption as part of the FORM-based upload.

The policy you provided, however, successfully blocks uploads through other methods unless they specify SSE.

Comment: Just a note, when you use the pre-signed URL approach, the policy string test only reads the request headers, not the query string contents. You can put whatever you like in the headers to make the policy pass, and then the query string contents determine what actually happens.

Comment: @w00t I thought pre-signed urls actually do not work with SSE-S3. Are you saying that to use this, the pre-signed urls should be accompanied with the "x-amz-server-side-encryption" header passed in by the client application in the http request?

Comment: @RichardN It's bean a year since I played with this so I'm not sure but yes, I think so…